# How prevent third party applications such as Internet Download Manager downloads pre-gziped files?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, iis, web-config, gzip

I need to compress my react project to `gzip` files for better performance in production mode. So I've compressed my react files with `compression-webpack-plugin`, the same as below in `webpack.config`:

```
 plugins: [
        new CompressionPlugin({
            algorithm: 'gzip',
            test: /\.(js)$|\.(css)$|\.(html)$|\.eot?.+$|\.ttf?.+$|\.woff?.+$|\.svg?.+$/,
        })
    ],
```

Here's the output folder:

[image]

I'm using Url rewriter to load `pre-gzip` files on the server instead of original `js` files on `web.config`:

```
  <rewrite>
      <outboundRules  rewriteBeforeCache="true">
          <rule name="Custom gzip file header">
              <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_CONTENT_ENCODING" pattern=".*" />
              <conditions>
                  <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="\.gz$" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" value="gzip"/>
          </rule>
      </outboundRules>
      <rules>
          <rule name="Rewrite gzip file">
              <match url="(.*)"/>
              <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern="gzip" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz" matchType="IsFile" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.gz" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

In addition I've installed [Internet Download Manager](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/) on my OS. My problem is that the Internet download manager, `gz` files downloader, has led to the website needing to be fixed! Here's a picture of the problem:

[image]

How can I not let a third-party application, such as Internet Download Manager, stay between the response sent from the server and the client that wants to receive it, and `gzip` files work appropriately?

Comment: download manager such as IDM installs extensions to browsers, either replacing browser's default downloader or hooking into pages when they are loaded. both cases, it is no more browser's job. you need to tell downloader not to interfere with your choice of extension.

Comment: @YılmazDurmaz So based on your description, I understood that we can't do anything to prevent `IDM` from this Behavior on code side! Yes?!

Comment: just like you click one a file and OS launches a program associated with the extension of the file, if download manager is set to intercept that extension, it is not avoidable. you can try the answer below to disable IDM for gzip files, or implement a name changer to get your files and unzip in the browser. you can do such conversion but i cant say how because i dont have experience for that. thinking it like base64 coded images might help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making a wrong request, you should make a request to `vendor.js`, and not `vendor.js.gz` (probably in your HTML). I never worked with IIS but the server should be configured in a way that if it gets the request header `Accept-Encoding: gzip` then it passes the gzipped file with the response header of `Content-Type: gzip`.

For example, if you look at StackOverflow requests, it gets some `.js` files with the response header of `Content-Type: gzip`. This tells the browser that the content should be uncompressed first.

[image: StackOverFlow request header with accept-encoding of gzip]

[image: StackOverFlow response header with content-type of gzip]

As you can see in the images, it's only a request to a `.js` file.

Comment: If you noticed to my question. you would understand that I have compressed my files before, therefor I'm rendering pre compressed files. In `stackoverflow ` there isn't any pre compressed files and its compress files with Web Server on the air!

Comment: @MajidM. I think your problem comes from the files extensions being `.gz`. Maybe put them in another directory with the same name as the javascript files, but also remove `.gz` and let their extension be `.js`. Then redirect your loads into them if the server requests with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! You gave me the clue and I tried to done the thing which yo said. Fortunately, I changed the IIS configuration and I could address the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps could help:

1. in the Internet Download Manager, open the options;
2. select file types;
3. you can either edit the file type (e.g. GZ, GZIP) or edit the sites list that don’t start downloading automatically

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I don't want to do it in Internet Download Manager. I would like to do it in Code on my application! :)

Comment: Well, in my understanding, the file must be downloadable, and the changes you required should be on the client side instead of the server side. But that's beyond my capability. I really wish you can find a perfect solution soon.