# Is there any way to reduce bundle size with removing unused part of node_modules packages?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm reducing `react` bundle files with `wepack`. Unfortunately, some packages have been used in the project and cannot be eliminated. One of them is `recharts` for drawing charts in reports. As you can see in the following picture, it has led to an increase in the massive size of the `vendors.js` file. Because of some reason which I've mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70497615/how-prevent-third-party-applications-such-as-internet-download-manager-downloads), I don't want to use `gzip` compression in `webpack`. I want to know if there is any way to remove the unused part of a package, such as `recharts` to reduce the whole package size in the finally created `vendors.js` file.

[image]

Here's the `webpack.config`:

```
var config = {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    cache: true,
    entry: {
        main: path.join(__dirname, "app", "App.js"),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'scripts', 'js'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',
        publicPath: '/scripts/js/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        babelrc: false,
                        presets: [
                            ['es2015', { modules: false }],
                            'react',
                        ],
                        plugins: [
                            'syntax-dynamic-import',
                            'transform-object-rest-spread',
                            'transform-class-properties',
                            'transform-object-assign',
                        ],
                    },

                },

            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: false,
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                defaultVendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: "vendors",
                    chunks: "all"
                }
            },
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.ts'],
        alias: {
            'react-loadable': path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/app.js'),
        },
    },
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
    config.output.chunkFilename = '[id].js'
    config.devtool = false;
    config.optimization = {
        chunkIds: "natural",
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: "vendors",
                    chunks: "all"
                }
            },
        }
    },
        config.plugins = [
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
                resourceRegExp: /^\.\/locale$/,
                contextRegExp: /moment$/,
            }),
            new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
                analyzerMode: 'static',
                generateStatsFile: false,
                openAnalyzer: false,
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production') }
            }),
        ];
}
module.exports = config;
```

For the final description, for example, I've changed the following import :

```
import {Bar, BarChart, CartesianGrid, Cell, LabelList, ResponsiveContainer, XAxis, YAxis} from 'recharts';
```

To:

```
import Bar from 'recharts/es6/cartesian/Bar';
import BarChart from 'recharts/es6/chart/BarChart';
import CartesianGrid from 'recharts/es6/cartesian/CartesianGrid';
import Cell from 'recharts/es6/component/Cell';
import LabelList from 'recharts/es6/component/LabelList';
import ResponsiveContainer from 'recharts/es6/component/ResponsiveContainer';
import XAxis from 'recharts/es6/cartesian/XAxis';
import YAxis from 'recharts/es6/cartesian/YAxis';
```

But it didn't have any observable effect!

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/recharts/babel-plugin-recharts? there are several comments that not everything is working really good